# How can I perform multiple ActiveMerchant payments atomically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

I have to create a subscription process which would involve two payments:

- The first one is the funding. Allowed payment types are regular mailing and ActiveMerchant checks (ACH) via Authorize.Net.
- The second one is the fees over the funding. Allowed payment types are the same as funding + credit card via Authorize.Net.

There is no way to do this in just one payment (specially if the customer wants to pay the fees with credit card), so I have to stick with:

- ActiveMerchant 1.55.0 (Ruby 2.2.0, Rails 4.2.0).
- Two different payments.
- The confirmation process will be a single hit to the backend which will hit the database and perform the two payments.

In order to atomically catch errors I could:

- Validate the models.
- Validate the payments (which are kind of transient models somehow).
- Perform payment 1 (funding).
- Perform payment 2 (fees).
- Store everything.

**But** these are external systems, which could fail by a variety of reasons, say:

- System entered on maintenance.
- Suspicious operation.
- Invalid card number.
- Invalid routing number.
- ...

So I reach a point where regular db transactions do not help (since this is about two operations in an external system), and **perhaps the funding payment works but the fee payment does not**.

Is there a way to *rollback* the first payment if the second payment fails, so either the two payments succeed or no payment does?